# Are Jewish conjoined twins permitted to marry?

Tags: halacha-theory, marriage, arayot

Being that it is forbidden to marry siblings may conjoined twins marry? Are they considered siblings or one person?

Comment: Is your question whether female conjoined twins may marry a single man? Or is it something else? Please clarify the question.

Comment: [There's a whole article on this](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol26Klein.pdf)

Comment: I’d think either way you have a problem - either they’re siblings, or they’re the same person. In either case marriage doesn’t apply.

Comment: @DonielF if they're one person, why wouldn't marriage apply?

Comment: @Daniel By definition marriage is between two separate people.

Comment: It just occurred to me that it’s scientifically impossible to have conjoined twins of different sexes. This case is not physically possible to occur.

Comment: I believe OP is asking if the twins may marry a third party.

Comment: @LN OP will have to weigh in on this, but to me “Being that it is forbidden to marry siblings” sounds like he’s asking if they can marry each other.

Comment: No I'm not asking if conjoined twins can marry each other. I'm asking if a regular person can marry conjoined twins.

Answer (score 0):

In 1977, Rav Moshe Feinstein ruled on a case of conjoined twins who were joined from the shoulder to the pelvis and shared a single six-chambered heart. I don't believe that his responsum was published by himself; however, I have seen multiple pages on the internet that cite a 1977 Philadelphia Inquirer article about his ruling (including [this one](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/assia_english/halperin2-1.htm), which I'm using as a basis for my summary because I do not have access to the article itself). Their condition was life-threatening to both of the twins to the extent that they would both almost certainly die if they were not separated. However, separating the twins would certainly cause the death of one of them.

Rav Moshe ruled that the twins may be separated, resulting in one of their deaths. He used two analogies to support his decision:

1. [Rodef (pursuer)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodef)
2. A case given in the Yerushalmi where bandits demand that a group of Jews hand over a particular Jew to be killed. The ruling there according to Reish Lakish (which is how we pasken for practical halakha), is that handing over the one designated Jew is permitted so the rest will not be killed.

Both of these analogies clearly assume that the conjoined twins are two separate people. If conjoined twins were considered one person in halakha, he would not need to go to such analogies because nobody would be killed by separating them. Given that they are separate people, **it is clear that two female conjoined twins could not marry one man** because one man may not marry two sisters. Likewise, two male conjoined twins could not both marry one woman since a woman may not marry two men at all (regardless of whether they are siblings).

Comment: @LN6595 Good point. I was just addressing what I assumed to be the meaning of the first part of the question (since the fact that male conjoined twins cannot marry one woman is not due to the fact that they are siblings), but I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: The twins can marry two different women and then fulfill the divine degree.

Comment: @Jonathan That might be true, though there would obviously be some practical and halakhic concerns that need to be worked out. But I don't think that's relevant to the question.

Comment: I think it is totally relevant to the question. I agree with you that halakhic concerns would need to be met, and I'm sure they would be acted accordingly.

Comment: If a conjoined twins counts as two people how is one able to decide who should die for the benefit of the other?

Comment: @Dude Typically, one is clearly more viable than the other. When that's not the case, perhaps neither one can be designated as the one that will die, but they're still two different people.

Comment: If one was more viable than the other this question wouldn't be relevant. This is about an adult conjoined twins that is of marriageable age

Comment: @Dude they are different cases. Rav Moshe's ruling was about baby conjoined twins. We see from that case that conjoined twins are considered two people. Now we apply that fact to your case of adult conjoined twins.

Comment: Sounds like a choice between murder and giloy arayos both of which are put on the same level of transgression